# Consultas SQL mostradas en una tabla html + php

Tags: html, postgresql

En este momento estoy trabajando en una consulta sencilla sql a traves de una busqueda contenida por una palabra almacenada en una variable, donde hago un select y pido que me muestre los resultados en una tabla en html, pero el problema es que si esa palabra tiene varios registros me crea varias tablas y lo que realmente deseo es que si la busqueda arroja varios registros me coloque un registro debajo del otro sin generarme mas tablas html.

```html
$query = "SELECT * FROM datos_usuarios WHERE LOWER(nombre_usuario) LIKE '%$palabra%' OR LOWER (apellido_usuario) LIKE '%$palabra%'";
$result = pg_query($query);
 
if ($palabra == null || $palabra =='')
    echo "necesita escribir algo, para buscar";
else
{
    $total = pg_num_rows($result);
    if($total != 0)
    {
        while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">        
        <title>Resultado de Busqueda</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstra337.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <h3>Datos Usuario</h3>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Apellido</th>
                    <th>Correo Electrónico</th>
                </tr>
               <tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <td><?php echo "$row[0]"; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo "$row[1]"; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo "$row[2]"; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo "$row[4]"; ?></td>            
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <a href="admin.php" class="btn btn-primary" align="center">Atras</a>
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>
    <?php
        }
    }
    else{
     echo "No se encontraron resultados";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No veo necesario desde mi punto de vista, que renderices la vista entera por cada registro que devuelva la consulta (headers, css, tablas, etc).

Lo que puedes hacer es ejecutar el `while` justo debajo de la etiqueta `<body>` y ahí no tendrías ningún inconveniente en mostrar varios registros (o no mostrar ninguno).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">        
      <title>Resultado de Busqueda</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstra337.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container">
      <?php
      $query = "SELECT * FROM datos_usuarios WHERE LOWER(nombre_usuario) LIKE '%$palabra%' OR LOWER (apellido_usuario) LIKE '%$palabra%'";
      $result = pg_query($query);
      if ($palabra == null || $palabra =='')
        echo "necesita escribir algo, para buscar";
      else {
        $total = pg_num_rows($result);
        if($total > 0) {
          ?>
          <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
              <h3>Datos Usuario</h3>
              <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Nombre</th>
                  <th>Apellido</th>
                  <th>Correo Electrónico</th>
              </tr>
            <tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <?php
              while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
              ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo "$row[0]"; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo "$row[1]"; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo "$row[2]"; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo "$row[4]"; ?></td>            
                </tr>
              <?php
              }
              ?>
              </tbody>
          </table>
          <a href="admin.php" class="btn btn-primary" align="center">Atras</a>
          <?php
        } else {
          echo "No se encontraron resultados";
        }
      }
      ?>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: El while lo habia agregado pero antes de comenzar el codigo html por eso era que me generaba varias tablas, muchas gracias tu idea me hizo solucionarlo, agrengando el while en el resultado solo me genera columnas mas no tablas.